# How do I make a spark DataGrid grow horizontally to fully render all the columns?

Tags: actionscript-3, datagrid, flex4.5, flex-spark, autosize

I've set a DataGrid to display all the rows in the data provider by binding it to the height of the control.
Now that all rows are rendered, I want the DataGrid to grow horizontally so that every column renders the whole text (of Labels).
Is there a way of doing this without resorting to a typical object?

thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the asdoc for the DataGrid component :

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/DataGrid.html

When you create a DataGrid, you also set its size.What you can do, however, is cycle through all the labels for a certain column, get the max value, and re-set the column minColumnWidth : 
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/DataGrid.html#minColumnWidth

Then, you would resize the DataGrid accordingly, and call invalidate() to redraw the component.